# How to compare objects by property names and values

Tags: typescript

Have to refactor the method that analyzes 2 objects of different type boolean properties. This is what I have after initial refactoring:

```
export interface IFirstType {
   propertyOne: boolean;
   propertyTwo: boolean;
   propertyThree: boolean;
   propertyFour: boolean;
   propertyFive: boolean; 
}
export interface ISecondType {
   firstProperty: boolean;
   secondProperty: boolean;
   thirdProperty: boolean;
   fourthProperty: boolean;
   fifthProperty: boolean; 
}

function CompareBooleanProperties(left: IFirstType, right: ISecondType): boolean {
    type PropertyPair<T = boolean, K = boolean> = { firstEl: T, secondEl: K };
    type PropertyPairs<P = boolean, R = boolean> = PropertyPair<P, R>[];

    const pairOne: PropertyPair = { firstEl: left.propertyOne!, secondEl: 
    right.firstProperty };

    const pairTwo: PropertyPair = { firstEl: left.propertyTwo!, secondEl: 
    right.secondProperty };
    //more property pairs go here.

    const pairs: PropertyPairs = [pairOne, pairTwo, pairThree, pairThree, pairFour, ...];

    return pairs.some(value => value.firstEl && value.secondEl);
}
```

This works for 2 given object types, how would I make it more generic to make it work with other types and iterating over their respective boolean properties.

Comment: Please [edit] the code here to be a [mre] that clearly demonstrates your issue when we copy and paste into our own IDEs.  Right now I see errors on `IComparisonGridRow` and `pairThree`, etc., which are presumably not what you're asking about and therefore distractions at best.

Comment: If you're looking to create a diff, this is actually quite complicated when values can be non-primitives. See https://github.com/JakobJingleheimer/form5/blob/main/lib/deepDiff.js

Comment: @JakobJingleheimer Thanks for reply. I am looking to create a diff, need to see if any pairs are `true` to be exact but need to account for `boolean` properties only however, so values are either `true` or `false`.

Comment: What do you mean by "other types" in _how would I make it more generic to make it work with other types_ then?

Comment: @JakobJingleheimer My method works with 2 objects of a given type, need to make it work with other types as well in my code base.

Comment: What is the shape of the other types? Are they arrays booleans? Nested plain objects? I think very likely, the deepDiff I linked above will do any of those (and more). It's not listed in npm but you can install it using the github url.

Comment: @JakobJingleheimer All objects are pretty much nested plain objects with linear properties, no nesting, just like those above. Thanks for sharing the link, would need to introduce `lodash` then to the code bases.

Comment: It uses just 4 utils from lodash; with tree-shaking, that's nothing ‍♂️ you'll probably need at least 1 of them anyway because detecting when something is a plain object is complicated. But if you're determined to write it yourself, use deepDiff as your working example.